# Move a row in excel using the keyboard

Tags: ms-office

In any editor I move lines around with the keyboard frequently. Using the mouse/trackpad is distracting and slow.  Can the same be accomplished in Excel and I just missed it?

Comment: What do you mean by "move lines around" in Excel?

Comment: Move row 1 to row 3. The "before" rows 2 and 3 become the "after" rows 1 and 2. This is trivial in editors.  After many perusals of keyboard shortcuts for excel I have never seen how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Space ␣</kbd> while on the row you want to move (row 1 in your example in the comments above). This should highlight all of the row.
2. Press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to cut the highlighted row.
3. Using the arrow keys on your keyboard, go to the row you want to insert the cut row before (row 4 if we continue the example).
4. Press <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.

Comment: Thx for jumping in!  great stuff!  Where/how did you find this? Any other gold nuggets of shortcuts up your sleeve?

Comment: Sorry but I don't remember how I found them all, especially the fourth step, probably trial & error. I just have been a heavy user of Excel (on the Windows side) for too many years until recently.

Comment: btw This also works for columns only that column is selected by `Ctrl-space` instead of `Shift-space`